# Create an envelope with different visibility of documents for users

Tags: docusignapi

I generate an envelope of 10-15 documents. There are two end users, the user that will sign should not see document 1 with the data of the second user. The second is to see all the documents.

I tried to use "excludedDocuments", but I come across the error "ACCOUNT_LACKS_PERMISSIONS".

The example I am generating (incomplete)

```
{"compositeTemplates": [
  {
    "inlineTemplates": [
      {
        "sequence": "1",
        "recipients": {
          "signers": [
            {
              "email": "albert@princeton.edu",
              "name": "Albert Einstein",
              "recipientId": "1",
              "clientUserId": "albert@princeton.edu",
              "routingOrder": "1",
              "tabs": {
                "textTabs": [],
                "radioGroupTabs": [],
                "checkboxTabs": []
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ],
    "document": {
      "documentId": 1,
      "name": "FirstFile",
      "transformPdfFields": "true"
    }
  },
  {
    "inlineTemplates": [
      {
        "sequence": "1",
        "recipients": {
          "signers": [
            {
              "email": "albert@princeton.edu",
              "name": "Albert Einstein",
              "recipientId": "1",
              "clientUserId": "albert@princeton.edu",
              "routingOrder": "1",
              "tabs": {
                "textTabs": [],
                "radioGroupTabs": [],
                "checkboxTabs": []
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ],
    "document": {
      "documentId": 2,
      "name": "SecondFile",
      "transformPdfFields": "true"
    }
  }
]}
```

Please tell me how to solve this problem. Thank you in advance

upd PHP7 code:

```
            $compositeTemplates[] = [
                'inlineTemplates' => [
                    [
                        'sequence' => '1',
                        'recipients' => [
                            'signers' => [
                                [
                                    'email' => $userData['email'],
                                    'name' => $userData['name'],
                                    'recipientId' => '1',
                                    'clientUserId' => $userData['email'],
                                    'routingOrder' => '1',
                                    "excludedDocuments" => ['1'],
                                    'tabs' => [
                                        'textTabs' => Template::fileTextTabs($sendData[$withoutExtension]['text'] ?? false), //here the simple formation of tabs according to what is
                                        'radioGroupTabs' => Template::fileRadioGroupTabs($sendData[$withoutExtension]['radio'] ?? false),
                                        'checkboxTabs' => Template::fileCheckboxTabs($sendData[$withoutExtension]['checkbox'] ?? false),
                                    ],
                                ],
                            ],
                            "carbonCopies" => [
                                [
                                    "email" => 'mylyrium@gmail.com',
                                    "name" => 'copies',
                                    "recipientId" => "2",
                                    "routingOrder" => '1',
                                ],
                            ],
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
                'document' => [
                    'documentId' => $id,
                    'name' => $filename,
                    'transformPdfFields' => 'true',
                ],
            ];
            $id++;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error means that the Admin account is not properly configured to have the document visibility enabled.
To do so, go to your [DocuSign Admin Account](https://admindemo.docusign.com/sending-settings) and scroll down to Sending Settings.
Make sure that one of the below options is selected instead of `Off`

[image]

For more information on the Document Visibility drop-down options, see the [official documentation](https://10226ec94e53f4ca538f-0035e62ac0d194a46695a3b225d72cc8.ssl.cf2.rackcdn.com/quick-start-document-visibility.pdf)

Comment: prompt please still such moment when I add in an exception a file in which there is "tabs:[]" to me drops out here such error "CANNOT_EXCLUDE_DOCUMENT"

Comment: If you look at the DocuSign errors list, it seems that this document has a reason god enough not to be excluded (https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/Content/Error%20Code/Error%20Codes%20and%20Associated%20Messages.htm) Can you share your code or the according JSON message ?

Comment: on the site under your link I was and saw the message " 
This document cannot be excluded for this recipient.". But in the document that I want to exclude there is no signature, only an array with fillable tabs. I will send you a fragment of my working code on the PHP.